# What is the correct command using brace expansions to create multiple directories?

Tags: command-line, bash

Could I use the following command to create multiple directories?:

```
mkdir ~/backups/freemem/{backups/diskuse,backups/openlist,backups/freedisk}
```

or

```
mkdir ~/backups/freemem/{/backups/diskuse/,/backups/openlist/,/backups/freedisk/}
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming `~/backups/freemem/backups` is an existing directory, both will work, since `~/backups/freemem//backups/diskuse/` and `~/backups/freemem/backups/diskuse` are the same as far as `mkdir` is concerned. But why not simplify that?

```
mkdir ~/backups/freemem/backups/{diskuse,openlist,freedisk}
```

If `~/backups/freemem/backups` doesn't exist yet, then neither will work. You need `mkdir -p` instead to create missing directories in the hierarchy.